# delphi Cromis.Scheduler required FreePascal unit

Tags: delphi, freepascal

recently i have created a small scheduler program using Cromis.Scheduler in delphi 10 Seattle. I manage to compile and run the program in windows environment.

Now, when i need to compile the same program in Android, the compiler telling me there are missing file and the problem is the missing file is .pp file (FreePascal) file, what should i do ? Thanks.

below is the code from Cromis.Scheduler

```
uses
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Windows, Messages,
{$ELSE}
  LMessages, LCLType, LCLIntf,
{$ENDIF}
  SysUtils, Classes, DateUtils, Math, Contnrs,

  System.Types,
  // cromis units
  Cromis.StringUtils;
```

*** i have download the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library supports Delphi on Windows, and Free Pascal with the Lazarus library. That is clear from the `uses` statement.

Android on Delphi is therefore not supported. This library is of no use to you when targeting Android from Delphi. You will need to find another way to solve your problem.

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong: what you means is i should not use this library if my program need to target on multiple platform ? if yes, do you have any idea what scheduler library should use if i need to use delphi to code and my target platform i iOS, Android and Windows. Thanks.

Comment: That is correct. This is not a library that supports your platforms. Asking for library recommendations is off topic here on SO. I just answered the question that you asked.